# Can't load zfs kernel module on Fedora with Secure Boot - "Required key not available"

Tags: fedora, uefi, zfs, secure-boot

### I'd like to use zfs with my Fedora 20 system.

I've installed the [ZFS on Linux Fedora repository](http://zfsonlinux.org/fedora.html) and subsequently the kernel-devel and zfs package. As far as I can tell, everything was installed successfully and I also rebooted the system. Nonetheless, `sudo zpool create` outputs errors:

```
Failed to load ZFS module stack.
Load the module manually by running 'insmod <location>/zfs.ko' as root.
```

Modprobe will also not load the module:

```
$ sudo modprobe zfs
modprobe: ERROR: could not insert 'zfs': Required key not available.
```

`insmod` with either of the two locations of `zfs.ko` I found on my system yields the same error:

```
$ sudo insmod /usr/lib/modules/3.16.3-200.fc20.x86_64/extra/zfs.ko
insmod: ERROR: could not insert module /usr/lib/modules/3.16.3-200.fc20.x86_64/extra/zfs.ko: Required key not available
$ sudo insmod /var/lib/dkms/zfs/0.6.3/3.16.3-200.fc20.x86_64/x86_64/module/zfs.ko
insmod: ERROR: could not insert module /var/lib/dkms/zfs/0.6.3/3.16.3-200.fc20.x86_64/x86_64/module/zfs.ko: Required key not available
```

### I'm booting with **UEFI**, having **SecureBoot enabled**.

I guess the kernel will only load modules that are signed with some trusted keys, probably those of the Fedora kernel team. For example `usb-storage` apparently has such a signature:

```
$ modinfo usb-storage | grep '^sig'
signer:         Fedora kernel signing key
sig_key:        55:46:C1:1D:28:CF:EC:0B:46:B1:C1:F1:93:0D:6B:F3:EC:63:B0:67
sig_hashalgo:   sha256
```

**What can I do to get ZFS running?**

**Edit:** I've tried to disable Secure Boot and I could in fact load the module without a problem. I don't like it as a solution, as Secure Boot [does provides some additional protection](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/16243/how-secure-is-microsoft-mandated-uefi-secure-boot-really) and my BIOS/UEFI *delays my boot process* to tell me it was booting insecurely.

Comment: Your on the right track your module need to be signed, but this will probably never happens, so the only solution I see is to disable secureboot

Comment: Can you check output of following command ?
- cat /proc/keys (This will list the keys registered in your system)
- dmesg | grep -i "Loaded x.509" 

It might be the case that probably the module signing verification failed for zfs. 
I think that your dmesg or syslogs will be having errors like  : "Request for unknown module key"

Answer (score 1):

Turn off secure boot, or sign the ZFS and SPL modules.

https://docs.fedoraproject.org/en-US/Fedora/26/html/System_Administrators_Guide/sect-signing-kernel-modules-for-secure-boot.html