# Required key not available when running nslookup, dig

Tags: dns, key-authentication, secure-boot

I upgraded my system recently, and now I am seeing a really bizarre error, any ideas on what I can do to fix this issue?:

```
nslookup 8.8.8.8
../../../../lib/isc/unix/socket.c:2135: internal_send: 192.168.43.232#53: Required key not available
../../../../lib/isc/unix/socket.c:2137: unable to convert errno to isc_result: 126: Required key not available
8.8.8.8.in-addr.arpa    name = dns.google.

Authoritative answers can be found from:
```

Edits:

Unfortunately I did not take note of which versions as it was done through the software center app, I'm running a variant of Ubuntu 18.04 ( pop_os )

`systemd-resolve --status`:

```
Global
     DNS Servers: 192.168.43.220


Link 3 (wlp113s0)
      Current Scopes: DNS
       LLMNR setting: yes
MulticastDNS setting: no
      DNSSEC setting: no
    DNSSEC supported: no
         DNS Servers: 192.168.43.232
                      2600:1014:b02f:45d5::c3
```

`nmap -p 53 -Pn 192.168.43.232`

```
Starting Nmap 7.60 ( https://nmap.org ) at 2019-07-26 14:00 CDT
Nmap scan report for 192.168.43.232
Host is up.

PORT   STATE    SERVICE
53/tcp filtered domain

Nmap done: 1 IP address (1 host up) scanned in 2.03 seconds
```

`dig 8.8.8.8`:

```
../../../../lib/isc/unix/socket.c:2135: internal_send: 192.168.43.232#53: Required key not available
../../../../lib/isc/unix/socket.c:2137: unable to convert errno to isc_result: 126: Required key not available

; <<>> DiG 9.11.3-1ubuntu1.8-Ubuntu <<>> 8.8.8.8
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NOERROR, id: 49678
;; flags: qr aa rd ra ad; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 1, AUTHORITY: 0, ADDITIONAL: 0

;; QUESTION SECTION:
;8.8.8.8.           IN  A

;; ANSWER SECTION:
8.8.8.8.        0   IN  A   8.8.8.8

;; Query time: 6 msec
;; SERVER: 2600:1014:b02f:45d5::c3#53(2600:1014:b02f:45d5::c3)
;; WHEN: Fri Jul 26 14:03:02 CDT 2019
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 41
```

Possibly related:

- https://askubuntu.com/questions/914997/install-virtualbox-while-keeping-secure-boot
- [Failed to insert 'vboxdrv': Required key not available](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/428810/failed-to-insert-vboxdrv-required-key-not-available)
- [Can't load zfs kernel module on Fedora with Secure Boot - "Required key not available"](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/157539/cant-load-zfs-kernel-module-on-fedora-with-secure-boot-required-key-not-avai)
- https://askubuntu.com/questions/891248/ubuntu-16-04-how-can-i-disable-secure-boot
- [Signed kernel modules - "not signed with trusted key"](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/472076/signed-kernel-modules-not-signed-with-trusted-key)
- http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/request_key.2.html

**possible solutions**

- Try unblocking port 53.
- I had an issue where docker-compose was doing something weird to the network, so I ran `docker-compose down && docker-compose up`

Comment: Update question with details of what you upgraded from, and what you upgraded to ?

Comment: What's 192.168.43.232? If it's a different machine to the one on which you're running `nslookup`, does it work correctly? Are you using DNSSec? What is in your client's `/etc/resolv.conf`? Does `dig 8.8.8.8` work any better?

Comment: A problem is that you're filtering tcp/53. Unblock that and try again.

Comment: @roaima Thank you so much. For some reason or another the iptables were messed up somehow. I ran `iptables -F` and can now nslookup.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One problem is that you're filtering TCP port 53. (DNS uses UDP for short quick queries, and TCP for longer messages.) Unblock that and try again.